# Plastic Bowl for Bread

Tags: baking

Is it ok to let bread rise in a plastic bowl?  I got rid of my glass and metal bowls because they were too heavy for me to lift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just OK, it's preferable.

If you walk into the back in a commercial small bakery, you'll see that pretty much all of their doughs rise in [plastic rising buckets](https://breadtopia.com/store/dough-bucket/). The first advantage of this is that such buckets have snap-on lids that eliminate the need to waste a lot of plastic wrap sealing in the dough.  The second advantage for bakeries (but probably not for you) is that they can be stacked.

The third advantage I can only give you from experience (I can't find a reference): the dough rises faster.  I believe this is because unlike metal, ceramic, or glass, the bowl does not conduct away the heat of the fermenting yeast.  Presumably a dough basket (another option for you in the "easy to lift" department) would work just as well.

Comment: Such great information, I appreciate your information.  I was aware that  bakeries use plastic buckets with lids but it just didn't occur to me to apply that to myself!

Comment: Thanks!  If that satisfies you, can you select my answer?

Comment: I would be happy to select your answer but I don't know how to do that,  a little instruction please?

Comment: Looks like you just figured it out!

Answer (score 5):

It really shouldn't be a problem.  A thick-walled bowl is usually preferred to help maintain an even rising temperature.  As long as it is food-safe, you keep it in a draft-free area, and it remains at a consistent temperature, you should be fine.